# What is a faster way to write this function to delete rows/objects in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, datatables

So, I have this function that, after an update, deletes elements from a table. The function, lets call it foo(), takes in one parameter.

```
foo(obj);
```

This object obj, has a subfield within called messages of type Array. So, it would appear something like this:

```
obj.messages = [...];
```

Additionally, inside of obj.messages, each element contains an object that has another subfield called id. So, this looks something like:

```
obj.messages = [{to:"You",from:"Me",id:"QWERTY12345.v1"}, ...];
```

Now, in addition to the parameter, I have a live table that is also being referenced by the function foo. It uses a dataTable element that I called oTable. I then grab the rows of oTable and copy them into an Array called theCurrentTable.

```
var theCurrentTable = oTable.$('tr').slice(0);
```

Now, where it gets tricky, is when I look into the Array theCurrentTable, I returned values appear like this.

```
theCurrentTable = ["tr#messagesTable-item-QWERTY12345_v1", ...];
```

The loop below shows how I tried to show the problem. While it works (seemingly), the function itself can have over 1000 messages, and this is an extremely costly function. All it is doing is checking to see if the current displayed table has the elements given in the parameter, and if not a particular element, delete it. How can I better write this function?

```
var theCurrentTable = oTable.$('tr').slice(0);
var theReceivedMessages = obj.messages.slice(0);

for(var idx = 0; idx < theCurrentTable.length; idx++){ // through display
    var displayID = theCurrentTable[idx].id.replace('messagesTable-item-','').replace('_','.');
    var deletionPending = true;
    for(var x = 0; x < theReceivedMessages.length; x++){
        var messageID = theReceivedMessages[x].id;
        if(diplayID == messageID){
            console.log(displayID+' is safe...');
            deletionPending = false;
        }
    }
    if(deletionPending){
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(idx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your problem. Your `<tr>` elements have an `id` that should match an item id within your messages.

First you should extract the message id values you need from the `obj` parameter

```
var ids = obj.messages.map(function (m) { return '#messagesTable-item-' + m.id; });
```

This will give you all the rows ids you need to keep and then join the array together to use jQuery to select the rows you don't want and remove them.

```
$('tr').not(ids.join(',')).remove();
```

Note: The [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is only supported from IE9 so you may need to use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

Comment: This deleted literally everything...is there anyway to make it more specific?

Comment: Are you sure the values in `ids` exactly match the id attribute for the `<tr>` elements you want to keep? `$(ids.join(','))` will show you what it matches. If there are no matches it does remove every `<tr>`. Use `console.log(ids);` to see what you have created. Instead of `.remove()` try `hide()` so you can still see the elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Set of the message ID values you have, so you can later detect if a given ID is in this Set in constant time.

Here is how that would look:

```
var theCurrentTable = oTable.$('tr').slice(0);
var theReceivedMessages = obj.messages.slice(0);

// Pre-processing: create a set of message id values:
var ids = new Set(theReceivedMessages.map( msg => msg.id ));

theCurrentTable.forEach(function (row, idx) { // through display
    var displayID = row.id.replace('messagesTable-item-','').replace('_','.');
    // Now you can skip the inner loop and just test whether the Set has the ID:
    if(!ids.has(displayId)) {
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(idx);
    }
});
```

So now the time complexity is not any more *O(n.m)* -- where *n* is number of messages, and *m* the number of table rows -- but *O(n+m)*, which for large values of *n* and *m* can make quite a difference.

Notes:

If *theCurrentTable* is not a true Array, then you might need to use a `for` loop like you did, or else use `Array.from(theCurrentTable, function ...)`

Secondly, the implementation of *oTable.fnDeleteRow* might be that you need to delete the last rows first, so that *idx* still points to the original row number. In that case you should reverse the loop, starting from the end.

Comment: I think there are a few syntax errors here. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: Yes, I could not test the code as the definition of *oTable* and *obj* were not specified. I corrected a few syntax issues just now, and added two notes to consider..